# MariaDB ODBC on Red Hat Linux

Tags: linux, mariadb, odbc, redhat, unixodbc

When I try to connect to a Maria DB from Power BI I get this error:

```
"The 'Driver' property with value '{MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver}' doesn't correspond to an installed ODBC driver."
```

In the Linux RedHat server itself when I run this command it just hangs, I dont get an error:

```
$ isql MariaDB
```

These are my configs:

in the "odbc.ini" file I just put a random username, password, and port. And the public IP of the linux server itself:

```
[MariaDB]
Description=MariaDB server
Driver=MariaDB
SERVER=the public IP address of the server where the mariaDB is
USER=random username
PASSWORD=random password
DATABASE=test
PORT=443
```

the odbcinst.ini file:

```
[MariaDB]
Description=MariaDB Connector/ODBC
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
Setup=/usr/lib64/libodbcmyS.so
Driver64=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
UsageCount=3
```

I need help with figuring out what i'm missing? Thank you

These are all the configs I did since I created the server:

```
yum install mariadb-server.x86_64
systemctl start mariadb
mkdir odbc_package
cd odbc_package
wget https://downloads.mariadb.com/Connectors/odbc/connector-odbc-3.1.7/mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64.tar.gz
tar -xvzf mariadb-connector-odbc-3.1.7-ga-rhel7-x86_64.tar.gz
sudo install lib64/libmaodbc.so /usr/lib64/
sudo install -d /usr/lib64/mariadb/
sudo install -d /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/
sudo install lib64/mariadb/plugin/auth_gssapi_client.so /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/
sudo install lib64/mariadb/plugin/caching_sha2_password.so /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/
sudo install lib64/mariadb/plugin/client_ed25519.so /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/
sudo install lib64/mariadb/plugin/dialog.so /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/
sudo install lib64/mariadb/plugin/mysql_clear_password.so /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/
sudo install lib64/mariadb/plugin/sha256_password.so /usr/lib64/mariadb/plugin/
sudo yum install unixODBC
##created a template file similar to the following, with a name like MariaDB_odbc_driver_template.ini:
[MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver]
Description = MariaDB Connector/ODBC v.3.1
Driver = /usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
##And then install it to the system's global /etc/odbcinst.ini file with the following command:
sudo odbcinst -i -d -f MariaDB_odbc_driver_template.ini
#create a template file similar to the following, with a name like MariaDB_odbc_data_source_template.ini:
[MariaDB-server]
Description=MariaDB server
Driver=MariaDB ODBC 3.0 Driver
SERVER=<your server>
USER=<your user>
PASSWORD=<your password>
DATABASE=<your database>
PORT=<your port>
#And then you can install it to the system's global /etc/odbc.ini file with the following command:
sudo odbcinst -i -s -l -f MariaDB_odbc_data_source_template.ini
```

Comment: The error message says that it is looking for a driver named `MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver` but your odbcinst.ini file defines the driver name (the value in the square brackets) as `MariaDB`.

Comment: I modified the name of the driver to "MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver" but I'm still seeing the same error: 

in the "odbcinst.ini" file: 

`[MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver]
Description=MariaDB Connector/ODBC v.3.1
Driver=/usr/lib64/libmaodbc.so
UsageCount=2`

in the " odbc.ini" file: 





`[MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver]
Description=MariaDB server
Driver=MariaDB ODBC 3.1 Driver
SERVER=13.68.145.11
USER=Rana
PASSWORD=Rashid123***
DATABASE=test
PORT=443`

Comment: At a command prompt, check the output from running  `odbcinst -j` to verify that unixODBC is looking for the .ini files in the /etc folder (if that's what you expect).

Comment: thanks for the help, the "USER DATA SOURCES" is showing as in a different path, do you know if this needs to be modified 

`[Rana@z2 etc]$ [Rana@z2 etc]$ odbcinst -j
unixODBC 2.3.1
DRIVERS............: /etc/odbcinst.ini
SYSTEM DATA SOURCES: /etc/odbc.ini
FILE DATA SOURCES..: /etc/ODBCDataSources
USER DATA SOURCES..: /home/Rana/.odbc.ini
SQLULEN Size.......: 8
SQLLEN Size........: 8
SQLSETPOSIROW Size.: 8
[Rana@z2 etc]$`

Comment: User data sources are only really needed for users who don't have (sudo) permissions to modify the System data sources, so you should be okay there.

Comment: When you say that you want to "connect … from Power BI" is that running on the same machine as the "Linux RedHat server" that is hosting the MariaDB server? If not, then you may not need to have the ODBC driver installed on the MariaDB machine, but instead you would need the driver to be installed on the machine that is running Power BI.

Comment: Did you ever resolve this problem?  I'm having the exact same issue

Answer (score 0):

Is the path to the ODBC driver location in your PATH?  That's a common reason why an ODBC driver cannot be located.

Comment: both "odbcinst.ini" & "odbc.ini" files are in /etc
& I can see the file "libmaodbc.so" in the path "/usr/lib64/". are the files supposed to be in different paths?